# OpenCL kernel and odd copy

Tags: c++, optimization, gpu, opencl, nvidia

I'm studying OpenCL and I'm trying to do this exercise but I don't know how to write the corresponding kernel code in order to avoid the branch-divergence problem.
[image: exercise]

I write something like that but I don't know if I'll problem or branch divergence

```
__kernel void oddcopy(const __global const int *a, __global int*b) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    if(gid%2==0){
    b[gid] = a[gid];
    }
}
```

I hope my question is clear because I'm not very well at English, sorry.

Thanks in advance for the help, if there are problems let me know!

Answer (score 0):

`if(gid%2==0)` is the opposite of `if(gid)`, the former is true for even numbers, the latter for odd ones.

Well, as it is written currently, half of the threads will do nothing.

Instead, you should use

```
__kernel void oddcopy(const __global const int *a, __global int*b) {
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    b[2*gid+1] = a[2*gid+1];
}
```

Then for copying odd elements of array with N elements in total, you launch only `N/2` threads, think carefully about how should that be rounded if `N` is not even.